# CSS Responsive tables using Twitter Bootstrap viewed on tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap CSS for creating a responsive table, which looks normal on the desktop, but is scrolls horizontally on a mobile device.

You can see it here:

http://www.bonhard.com/nastodolci/penzion/ceny/

The CSS I'm using is this:

```
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table > thead > tr > th,
  .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > th,
  .table-responsive > .table > tfoot > tr > th,
  .table-responsive > .table > thead > tr > td,
  .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > td,
  .table-responsive > .table > tfoot > tr > td {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered {
    border: 0;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:first-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:first-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:first-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:first-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:first-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:last-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:last-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:last-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:last-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:last-child,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
  }
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > th,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > th,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > td,
  .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > td {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Now this works fine on desktop and mobile.  However on tablet it's displaying funny.  Check it out with your window resized to 1024x768

Do you know if I can tweak the media query values to make it behave on tablet the same as on mobile?

many thanks!

Phil

Comment: u can wrap your table within `<div class='col-sm-12'></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Add another `@media (max-width: 1024px) {}` ?? to have responsive in 1024px

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in css file..

```
@media (max-width: 1052px) {
  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just changed the media query value to 1050px and it works like a charm!

thanks!

Phil